# What's the meaning of 上 in 你还自恋上了?

Tags: complement

> 你还自恋上了.

What's the meaning of 上 here? Would this sentence be OK without 上? The context is here, in 29:45: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=k7TaJmcCYpI

Comment: Are you sure it wasn't [ 你] [还自(是)] [恋上了] (他)?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oh oh, 郑爽 is in trouble with her big mouth! 烦死了！

上：(probably): getting

你还自恋上啦！
You're getting narcissistic!

Maybe you could rewrite as: 你还开始自恋了。

Answer (score 3):

Here 上 marks the entry into a state, the state of 自恋.

Without 上 it could also mean that the person entered the state of 自恋, because 了 at the end of a sentence has the meaning of 'change of state'.

But it would be less evident than with 上.

Answer (score 2):

上 here means:

> 表示动作开始并继续(the action starts and continues)

e.g. 大家又聊上了。